# Using conditionals in one line in rails

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

Is this a valid way to impose a condition on a statement? I was having trouble using multiple &&'s or ||'s when using it in one line the other day.

```
@sales_opportunities << auction unless auction.company == current_user || !(auction.bids & current_user.bids).empty? || !auction.condition.include?(part.condition)
```

Comment: Did you get an error or just get a result you weren't expecting?

Comment: @JohnFeltz I'm just wondering if it's ok to put multiple conditions in one line after `unless` like that

Comment: no matter if valid or not. it is unreadable. refactor, move your conditions into a method.

Comment: Your example either raised an exception or returned a result that was not what you wanted. Which is it? That's important information, which is why @John's raised the question, which you have not answered. If you actually haven't run any code, you can answer your own question by simply running a few examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1. You can certainly put multiple conditions into one line after "unless"
2. If you do so, you may need to confirm they return the proper results, even with edge cases (make sure that the || or && has the proper scope, you may want parens to be explicit)
3. Nonetheless, this is pretty hard to read. I would suggest pulling those conditionals out and making each into its own method. This will make it more readable, and if you need those conditions elsewhere, it will make your code more DRY.

Comment: so something like
    @sales_opportunities << auction unless auction.belongs_to_current_user? || auction.includes_current_user_bid? || auction.doesnt_include_condition

Comment: See @SergioTulentsev 's answer, he hits the nail on the head.

Answer (score 2):

What @CaptainChaos and @PascalBetz said. At the very minimum, extract parts of that condition to local vars with descriptive names. Something like this:

```
insider_user     = auction.company == current_user
user_placed_bids = (auction.bids & current_user.bids).present?
part_matches     = auction.condition.include?(part.condition)

@sales_opportunities << auction unless insider_user || user_placed_bids || !part_matches
```

Now this looks much more manageable, heh?

Comment: In this specific case, maybe the keyword `or` is more readable than `||`.

Comment: @Aetherus: debatable. Me, I clench my teeth when I see `or` in a conditional :)